# React is not using the specified proxy to communicate with Flask backend server

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I am using a Flask server functioning as an API that serves information to the React frontend, I have the following fetch statement:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/time")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setCurrentTime(data.time);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }, []);
```

This is to fetch from my Flask server using the proxy `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",` in my `package.json` file but the fetch throws an error every time: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`.
Here's the Flask function `time`

```
@app.route("/time")
@cross_origin()
def get_current_time():
    return {"time": time.time()}
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong? It worked earlier then I closed everything to grab some food and didn't work when I came back so I guess I forgot to save whatever I did that originally made it work, who knows.

UPDATE (Minimal reproducible example):
app.py

```py
from flask import Flask
import time

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/time")
def get_current_time():
    print(time.time())
    return {"time": time.time()}
```

App.tsx

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState("0");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/time")
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((text) => {
        console.log(text);
        setCurrentTime(text);
      });
  });

  return (
    <>
      <p>The current time is {currentTime}.</p>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The error returned is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="module"> import RefreshRuntime from "/@react-refresh" RefreshRuntime.injectIntoGlobalHook(window) window.$RefreshReg$ = () => {} window.$RefreshSig$ = () => (type) => type window.__vite_plugin_react_preamble_installed__ = true </script>

<script type="module" src="/@vite/client"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> 

<title>Vite + React + TS</title> </head>

<body> <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx?t=1684083687489"></script>
</body> </html>
```

Comment: This looks fine to me, but if it's causing problems, I would log the actual error with `fetch("...").then(res => res.text()).then(text => console.log(text))`, and then add real error handling in the long run `if (!response.ok) { .... }` and a `catch`. Your server is probably running on debug and trying to return an error view. Also, are you looking at the server logs?

Comment: The HTML that the error returns _seems_ to just be the page itself which seems really weird, how would I go about finding the server logs?

Comment: Look at the console when the server is running. If the page returned is HTML, then you're probably hitting some different route than you think, because the route you've shown here is returning JSON. It looks like the fetch is to the `/time` route, so I'll need a [mcve] to be able to help further--there's no way to account for the HTML response based on the code shown.

Comment: @ggorlen I've added the minimal amount of each file that is required, maybe this issue is in another file but these are the only ones I have written (aside from adding the proxy to package.json), so I don't understand how anything else could have caused it.

Comment: Thanks, these looks 100% fine to me. I don't see any way `console.log(text);` could log the HTML. It'd be either an error or the JSON string.